# iPhone Music app is displaying a disabled podcast episode

Tags: iphone, podcasts

After syncing my iPhone with iTunes, I now somehow have a "disabled" podcast episode:

- All of the text is grey and there's no artwork
- I can't play the episode even though it displays "19m left"
- I can't delete the episode (swiping to delete does nothing)

How and why did this happen? And is there any way that I can either restore the episode so I can play it back, or simply delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it without having to sync anything - I simply went to the iTunes Store on my phone and downloaded the disabled episode. Once it was done, I still couldn't play it, but I could delete it. I did so and now it's gone.

I still don't know what exactly caused this to happen in the first place though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my musics. Try removing ONE single ipod episode (any episode is good) and sync the iPhone.

It should now sync everything but that one episode. You can put it back and sync it again and you're good to go.